# prepare food or prepare dishes in AE

Tags: american-english

Question for American English - is it more usual to use "prepare food" or to use
"prepare meals" or "prepare dishes"
The whole sentence is:
We prepare delicious dishes (food, meals) with special care and love.

Comment: I vote for "meals." I'm an American, by the way. This is not to say other Americans might prefer either "food" or "dishes," but "meals" just sounds right to me. On the other hand, if the sentence is designed to be part of an advertising campaign, the alliterative double D of "delicious dishes" might work better.

Comment: All work, it depends on what you want. 'dishes to emphasize a particular recipe, 'meals' fir the whole occasion, and 'food' for generically unspecified.

Comment: _Prepare_ is a very formal verb. The more normal verbs are _fix, make,_ and _cook_ (if cooking is involved). Simple Action _do_ is very common (_Who's doing supper tonight?_).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, one prepares food in a kitchen. The connotation is the work involved in getting food ready for cooking. One can prepare the potatoes, but that isn't a meal.

One prepares meals (with multiple ingredients) for oneself or one's family. The connotation is that what is prepared is what is required for sustenance, or nurturing.

One prepares dishes (has a connotation of more work/skill required) for company, special occasions, particular cuisines, etc. For example, one prepares a French dish. One prepares 'favorite dishes'. We prepared dishes of roasted curried sweet potatoes, cranberry apple chutney, etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That is very helpful. So I will go for dishes because we are talking about a restaurant. Sorry that I can't give you vote ups because I still don't have the right to do so.